# How to add field collection date field in scheduling component drupal 7?

Tags: entities, rules

I am using drupal 7 , I have used date field in field collection , I want to send email before one week of field collection date , I have made one Rule component which sends email to author , when I made a new rule of after adding new field collection item and make an action to schedule my component , in there I never got the option in date selector to set field collection date value

please help me out 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im working on a similar scenario and I'm also stuck with the same issue.
Try adding Entity has field and Data comparison conditions.
Check this link: http://www.drupalcommerce.org/faq/rules-field-data-selection